# How to use boost::simple_segregated_storage?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-pool

I try to use the boost::simple_segregated_storage, but I can`t understand how to use it correctly. There are no any samples. I use it in next way:

```
boost::simple_segregated_storage<int> pStorage;

const int num_partitions = 100;
const int partition_sz = sizeof(int);
const int block_sz = partition_sz * num_partitions;
int block[block_sz] = {};

pStorage.segregate(block, block_sz, partition_sz);

int* pInt = (int*)pStorage.malloc(); // <-- Crashes here
```

But I received crash. What I do wrong and where mistake?
How to use it in right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `pStorage.add_block(block, block_sz, partition_sz);` instead of `segregate()`, as `segregate()` is just for segregating block into chunks(I assume you know the concept of block and chunk, if not, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15942012/whats-the-difference-between-boostpoolmalloc-and-boostpoolordered-m/22779408#22779408) is an illustration). `add_block()` segregates `block` and merge its free list into `pStorage`'s free list. After `add_block()`, pStorage is not empty and you can allocate memory from it.